# SQL query open url in row

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

Hi im using MySQLWorkbench to query a a database that holds some URL's in a table im trying to find a way to query the database by selecting a certain tuple in the table that holds the link url and opening it in a browser, is this possible?

Comment: Is the issue working out the statement, the tuple, or getting MySQLWorkbench to open a link in a URL?

Comment: getting MySQLWorkbench to open a link in a URL